# Get key from hashMap in React-Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, hashmap

I have a hashMap as response from server that looks like this :

```
"data": {
        "1549969678424": "26.092242876805436"
    }`
```

How can I take the key and the value from it in two separate variables?

Comment: `Object.keys(dataFromServer)` to get the keys and `Object.values(dataFromServer)` to get the values. or see `Object.entries(dataFromServer)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
const data = {
            "1549969678424": "26.092242876805436"
        }

const keys = Object.keys(data);
const values = Object.values(data);
```

Hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: no need to do a map on the keys to get the values, see my comment above..

Comment: Yes, i know but i am not sure whether index of keys and values will be in sync if we use Object.values() or it will return values in any random order.

Comment: try it, they will be :)

Comment: Updated. Thanks @HatemAlimam.

Answer (score 0):

A few ways to go about this:

```js
var json = {
  data: {
    "1549969678424": "26.092242876805436"
  }
};

// Keys[0] and Values[0]
console.log(Object.keys(json.data)[0]);
console.log(Object.values(json.data)[0]);

// Entries
var entry = Object.entries(json.data)[0];

console.log('key', entry[0]);
console.log('value', entry[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

const data {

"key" : "value",
"key1" : "value1"
}

Comment: 1. Not JavaScript. 2. Doesn't answer question.